# Mysql, Sequelize How to delete multiple rows at once given an array of ids

Tags: mysql, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to delete multiple rows in a MYSQL database using Sequelize.

I have a delete mutation that receives an array of ids as an argument and I would like to delete rows in the database matching these ids.

Only the first row is deleted

**SCHEMA**

```
deletePropertyItems(id: [Int]!): DeletePropertyItemsRes!
```

**MUTATION**

```
async deletePropertyItems(_, { id }, { models }) {
      try {
        const deletedRows = await models.PropertyItem.destroy({
          where: { id: id },
        });

        if (deletedRows) {
          return {
            success: true,
            message: "Property Item(s) Deleted Successfully!",
          };
        }
        return {
          success: false,
          message: "Operation not successful!",
        };
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    },
```

Comment: what happens if you hardcode some ids, making the where clause: `where: { id: [1,2,3,4,5] }` ? Also what is the value of the function argument id?

Comment: The mutation works fine. All rows are deleted but sequelize deletes only one item

Comment: You mean that the deletedRows is always 1 if it deletes at least 1 row ?

Comment: The value of the function argument id is an array [1,2,3] something like that.  My point is only one row is affected. Only the first id of the array argument is executed. For some reasons other the rest of ids are ignored

Comment: it shouldn't behave like that, i'm using destroy with array and it deletes all the rows, if your arrays aren't big enough consider doing a loop to delete one item at a time, notice that it will do 1 delete query for each item. So im guessing your version of sequelize have a bug, so consider opening a ticket in the github repo of sequelize

Comment: Also check if the generated query is the desired one, for that you need to log sequelize generated queries

Comment: I fixed it, problem was on my frontend. The function I was using on my frontend was passing only one id.

Comment: That's why i've asked you to give the value of the function argument id in my first comment